# Why are data-uk attributes not applied when using UIkit (from getuikit) in React?

Tags: reactjs, getuikit

I recently noticed that, for some reason, UIkit was no longer picking up the `data-uk-dropdown` attributes in my React project. E.g. this no longer worked

```
  <div data-uk-dropdown="mode: click">
    <ul className="uk-nav uk-dropdown-nav">
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I also noticed that in the UIkit `boot` function in the UIkit core, the  `applyChildListMutation` handler was installed but never called back. This leads me to believe that the code to initialize UIkit was not playing nicely with React (anymore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual thing that was missing was this import statement: `import UIkit from 'uikit';`. You need this even when you are not referencing UIkit in the code (it probably triggers the loading of the required library code).

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to fix the original problem, but using the UIkit help I realized that I can use Javascript to solve it like this:

```
<div ref={(x: any) => {UIkit.dropdown(x, {mode: 'click'});}}>
  <ul className="uk-nav uk-dropdown-nav">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This has the added benefit of type-checking the properties that you pass to `UIkit.dropdown`.